# Don't want select query to stop at first match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I have this select query in a server:

> password = "%{sql:SELECT password FROM list WHERE Account = 'their_username' AND %{sql:SELECT status FROM member WHERE login = 'their_username'"

I have multiple passwords in the table "list" for each user. Right now this only works if the password variable in the beginning of that statement matches the first password in "list".

But I want the query to look through the other passwords, and for this to work if any of the passwords match the password variable from the beginning of the statement.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM list WHERE Account='their_username' AND password='their_password'`, then check that a row came back.

Comment: Is that MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? You have something else mixed in with the SQL code, what is that? You have one incomplete and one complete SQL query in the code, are they supposed to interact somehow?

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing passwords in plain text :(

Comment: Thanks all for a such quick response! I will look at these and get back.

Answer (score 1):

First Question:  What is the ultimate variable you want to extract from the database?  Is it the user's status?

Second Question:  Are you trying to manipulate the set of passwords for the user, or are you simply trying to determine whether the password given matches ANY one of the passwords associated with the user (as opposed to JUST the first)?

Look at your query again and ask yourself: What is the name of the second column I am testing against?

What I'm seeing in your query is

```
SELECT password FROM list 
    WHERE Account = 'their_username' 
        AND (something missing) = 
            SELECT status FROM member WHERE login = 'their_username'
```

In reality, I think your tables should be set up such that your query would look more like this

```
SELECT password FROM list,member 
    WHERE member.login = 'loginName' AND list.MemberID = member.ID
```

Play around with this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41c9e4/4), and check out some material on [relational algebra](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Syllabus/4-RelAlg/intro.html)

Comment: First Question: Trying to see if the password variable in beginning of statement matches ANY one of the passwords. Second Question: trying to determine whether the password given matches ANY one of the passwords associated with the user (as opposed to JUST the first)

Comment: I accidentally did leave out some of the query. To simplify, I think we can concentrate just on first part of query: SELECT password FROM list WHERE Account = 'their_username'

Comment: I can't however insert the password variable in beginning of statement into the Select query, like password = 'their_password' as mentioned by others here

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I'm helping with this, with such obvious and severe security issues in play, but you should do a JOIN on the two tables:

```
SELECT l.password 
FROM member m
INNER JOIN list l ON l.login = m.Account
WHERE m.Account = 'their_username' and l.password='the_password'
```

Then you should go back learn how to correctly handle passwords: what it means to salt and hash a password. Even better: never ever ever write your own authentication code. Instead, lean as much as possible on the authentication features provided to you by your platform of choice, as it's just so easy to write authentication code that seems to work, passes comprehensive unit tests, and is still flawed such that your app is cracked hard.

Comment: This is not for a typical password scenario. It is for use in a server implementation and this isn't for regular user auth. Anyway to do what you're talking about with having 'the_password'. I'm unable to put that variable into the statement/query.

Comment: Then you have return a query with all of the possible results and iterate over them on the client.

Answer (score 0):

This should return all passwords! May be you have only one combination of username-status in your table.

```
username   status    password
abc123     online    pppp
abc123     online    qqqq
def456     online    rrrr
def456     offline   ssss
```

If username is abc123 it will return only one password, but for def456 it will return both!
Can you post your list table for more understanding!

Comment: I will post table list when I can. My situation is like your abc123 example. I'm trying to determine whether the password given matches ANY one of the passwords associated with the user (as opposed to JUST the first). But I'm trying to do this without being able to directly compare the given/variable password inside the SQL query. Not sure if that makes sense lol or how to describe it